# npm audit not working on Windows using bash

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

I am using [`Mintty 2.8.4`](https://github.com/mintty/mintty) as my terminal to install npm packages.

I installed an earlier version of an npm package called `moment` and I got warnings about vulnerabilities. One of the suggestions my terminal gave me was to run `npm audit`. On running that command my terminal doesn't recognize it. It throws a list of other recognized commands instead.

Can anyone help me with explaining how to run `audit` on this terminal?

I have attached a detailed image of the error and the terminal I am using.

---

[image: printscreen of npm audit not working]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`npm audit` has just been introduced in npm 6, I see you’re running 5.6.0.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit

They have probably made the security reports available in npm 5 as well, but you need npm 6 to run audit.

Upgrading npm will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, it works now. O zi buna ;)

Comment: No worries. Multumesc:)

Answer (score 5):

It says exactly what you need to do:

> Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.

Comment: It makes sense now that you pointed it out. I've only just started using npm and I'm still trying to get my head around it. Thanks for the help.